# Restricted permutations between 4 groups and 2 replicates each

Tags: r, sas, permutation

I am trying to compare 4 groups with 2 samples each (replicates) to understand the differences among each group for a set of 10,000+ genes from a micro array project. I am using the method of permutations and calculating an F statistic as the sample size is too small for a standard t test.

Sample Data:

```
Gene    A1  A2  B1  B2  C1  C2  D1  D2
gene1  1.1 1.2 4.2 4.1 8.2 8.2 5.9 6.1 
gene2  2.7 2.6 3.1 2.9 7.2 7.8 7.1 7.0
.
.
gene10000 10.1 11.1 2.9 3.1 3.8 3.7 7.2 7.3
```

Using an F-statistic and a null of no mean difference, I was able to calculate the obs F- value for each gene in R. But when doing permutations, I understand that there will be 8C2 * 6C2 * 4C2 *2C2 different pairwise permutations which need to be accounted for. I am unable to code for these 2520 permutations in R.

Is there a package that I could look for in R or SAS macro that would help me getthe EXACT ORDER of the permutations? I tried the allPerms function from the 'permute' package and the permn function from the 'cominat' package but I get all possible permutations and not the restricted permutations of interest. I have seen codes in Pearl and python to do restricted permuations but I am not so well versed in either to modify the code.

For Eg. for 2 group (G1 and G2) setting with 2 replicates each (A1, A2 and B1, B2):

```
    G1   G2    
  A1 A2 B1 B2 
P1: A1 A2 B1 B2 
P2: A1 B1 A2 B2 
P3: A1 B2 A2 B1 
P4: A2 B1 A1 B2 
P5: A2 B2 A1 B1 
P6: B1 B2 A1 A2
```

> I want to get the exact order of permutations in a 4 group with 2 samples each setting i.e. 2520 rows and 8 columns.

Thanks!

Comment: I saw your email to me with the content of this question but thought I'd respond here for the record; you are right, **permute** can't do this. Allowing it is on my to do list but it is non-trivial to allow for random draws from the set of permutations without generating all the permutations and I need both all permutations and random permutations from the set if I am to add this to the package. There are [functions in Sage for this](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/combinat/sage/combinat/set_partition_ordered.html#sage.combinat.set_partition_ordered.OrderedSetPartition)

Comment: Thanks Gavin! I'll check that out!

Answer (score 1):

I ended up coding a function myself to achieve for a 4, 6 or 8 sample setting, the pairwise permutations:

```
>library(combinat)
> # function to show columns not in master data set
>"%w/o%" <- function(x, y) x[!x %in% y] #--  x without y
> permutations <- function(n, data)  {
  if(n %% 2 == 0)
  {
   if(n==2|n==4)
   {
    x <- t(combn(data,2))
    p <- nrow(x)
    A <- matrix(nrow= p , ncol = n )
    all <- matrix(data= c(rep(data)), nrow= p, ncol = n, byrow=T)
    for(i in 1: p)
    {
     A[i,] <- cbind(all[i,] %w/o% x[i,], x[i,])
    }
    return(matrix(A))
}
else if(n==6)
  {
   x <- t(combn(data,2))
   p <- nrow(x)
   A <- matrix(nrow= p*n , ncol = n ) # n=6
   all <- matrix(data= c(rep(data)), nrow= p, ncol = n, byrow=T)
   for( j in 1 :p)
   {
    absent <- all[j,] %w/o% x[j,]
    mat <- matrix(permutations(n-2, absent), ncol =n-2)
    present <- matrix(rep(x[j,], each = n), ncol =2)
    A[(j-1)*n+1:n,] <- cbind(present, mat)
   }
   return(matrix(A))
  }
else if(n==8)
  {
   x <- t(combn(data,2))
   p <- nrow(x)
   A <- matrix(nrow= 6*15*p , ncol = n ) # n=8
   all <- matrix(data= c(rep(data)), nrow= p, ncol = n, byrow=T)
   for( j in 1:p)
    {
    absent <- all[j,] %w/o% x[j,]
    mat <- matrix(permutations(n-2, absent), ncol =n-2)
    present <- matrix(rep(x[j,], each = 90), ncol =2)
    A[(j-1)*90+1:90,] <- cbind(present, mat)
   }
   return(matrix(A))
  }
}
   else 
    return("NA");
}

# m<- matrix(permutations(6, LETTERS[1:6]), ncol =6)
m <- matrix(permutations(8, LETTERS[1:8]), ncol =8)
```